# How can I run Apache virtual hosts as a certain user?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have several virtual hosts, and I want to run each one of them on a separate user to isolate the websites from each other. I have searched for a solution, but I can't find an up-to-date solution. What's the best way to run each virtual host asa separate user?

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to achieve? Is the goal to make it so that files don't have to be world-readable? Or is the goal to make scripts run as a particular user so each virtual host has its own security context on the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is in 11.10 but look into

http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/

It allows you to set a user/group per vhost

Comment: [Looks like a yes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=apache2-mpm-itk).